# Bootstrapper window that appears after restarting the computer

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

How is this behavior set? I can't find how to disable the bootstrapper from booting on reboot. I will install the program, turn off the computer and on the next day, when I start the computer, the bootstrapper window appears. Even though it will uninstall the bootstrapper. And when I installed it several times in tests, it happens that later I have several windows. But this pop-up doesn't always happen, and I don't know what it depends on.

**Edit**

Looking at the logs after the RegisterBegin:

> Session begin, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{bf97c7e8-2ef4-4439-9504-96a7736c10f4},
> options: 0x4, disable resume: No  Registering bundle dependency
> provider: {bf97c7e8-2ef4-4439-9504-96a7736c10f4}, version: 1.0.120.0
> Updating session, registration key:
> SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{bf97c7e8-2ef4-4439-9504-96a7736c10f4},
> resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No

You see `disable resume: No`, I can't find anything about it, but maybe it causes the application to run after reboot.

**Edit2**

It happen because bootstrapper add register HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce.

But can't find how turn off it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the reason for this was adding the RunOnce registry for the bootstrapper. It is written on the Internet that, according to the developers, this is a confirmation of the success of the installation. But in my case, it is unnecessary for me, because I do the post-configuration test myself. To prevent this, I hooked up to the OnRegisterComplete event and remove all registers containing the name of my installer.

However, this requires running the bootstrapper with administrative privileges.

```
    private void OnRegisterComplete(object sender, RegisterCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string registryKey = @"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce";
            RegistryKey key32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
            RegistryKey key = key32.OpenSubKey(registryKey, true);
            if (key != null)
            {
                var names = key.GetValueNames();
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    var value = key.GetValue(names[i]);
                    if (value.ToString().Contains("NameInstaller.exe"))
                        key.DeleteValue(names[i]);
                }
                key.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```